# make zram use lz4 compression algorithm

Tags: swap, compression, zram

Ubuntu 18, trying to make `zram` to use `lz4` compression.

Tried modifying `/usr/bin/init-zram-swapping` file

```
#!/bin/sh
...........
...........
for i in $(seq ${NRDEVICES}); do
  DEVNUMBER=$((i - 1))
  echo $mem > /sys/block/zram${DEVNUMBER}/disksize
  echo lz4 > /sys/block/zram${DEVNUMBER}/comp_algorithm # <= added this line
  mkswap /dev/zram${DEVNUMBER}
  swapon -p 5 /dev/zram${DEVNUMBER}
done
```

But, after reboot`zramctl` still shows I'm using `lzo` algortihm

```
NAME       ALGORITHM DISKSIZE  DATA  COMPR TOTAL STREAMS MOUNTPOINT
/dev/zram3 lzo           466M  2.9M 614.2K    1M       4 [SWAP]
/dev/zram2 lzo           466M  2.9M 631.2K    1M       4 [SWAP]
/dev/zram1 lzo           466M  2.9M 536.1K 1020K       4 [SWAP]
/dev/zram0 lzo           466M    3M   610K    1M       4 [SWAP]
```

I also tried adding adding it in`rc.local`, but it throws `device already in use warning`, because as far as I know, the change needs to be done before `mkswap` and `swapon` runs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works:

```
# initialize the devices
for i in $(seq ${NRDEVICES}); do
  DEVNUMBER=$((i - 1))
  echo lz4 > /sys/block/zram${DEVNUMBER}/comp_algorithm
  echo $mem > /sys/block/zram${DEVNUMBER}/disksize
  mkswap /dev/zram${DEVNUMBER}
  swapon -p 100 /dev/zram${DEVNUMBER}
done
```

**Note**: it seems you need to define the compression algorithm before zram size. Set `swapon -p` to priority level `100` to use zram actively as it improves performance.

Comment: Yes, it seems you need to define the compression algorithm before zram size. Set swapon -p to 100 swapiness to use zram actively as it improves performance.

Comment: thanks, i will check after going home. Too excited if this works :D

Comment: IMHO I don't understand why you use `swapon -p 100` here, rather than `sysctl vm.swappiness=100`?

Comment: Tomofumi I don't know. Please tell if you find out.

Comment: swapon -p 100 indicates the priority amongst swap partitions. You may have for example, a priority 10 zram swap and a priority 20 hdd swap partition.
swappiness is instead the threshold of free memory at which point the system starts to use the swap.

Comment: `swapon -p 100` will have no effect here, that's just a relative priority amongst all the swap partition (if there is for example still a disk swap), you probably indeed meant `swappiness`